# Splitting json object

Tags: java, json, split, code-splitting

I have JSON output from SQL statement as below

```
{
   "idno":6473853,
   "user":"GCA_GB",
   "operation":"U",
   "timestamp":"2022-08-22T13:14:48",
   "first_name":{
      "old":"rak",
      "new":"raki"
   },
   "fam_name":{
      "old":"gow",
      "new":"gowda"
   }
}
```

there is posibility that along with first name and family name we may get initial and nickname

i  want to split above json as below

```
{
   "idno":6473853,
   "user":"GCA_GB",
   "operation":"U",
   "timestamp":"2022-08-22T13:14:48",
   "first_name":{
      "old":"rak",
      "new":"raki"
   }
}
```

```
{
   "idno":6473853,
   "user":"GCA_GB",
   "operation":"U",
   "timestamp":"2022-08-22T13:14:48",
   "fam_name":{
      "old":"gow",
      "new":"gowda"
   }
}
```

can someone help me with this

Comment: What is stopping you from creating two separate JSON objects and filling them with data you want? Are you facing any *specific* problem?

Answer (score 0):

From your JSON data structure, I guess there are 4 fixed fields named `idno`, `user`, `operation`, `timestamp`. All the others are various object nodes, each with old value and new value. And you want to seperate all the object nodes. The following solution will seperate them and put them into an array node.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

Deserialization

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "   \"idno\":6473853," +
    "   \"user\":\"GCA_GB\"," +
    "   \"operation\":\"U\"," +
    "   \"timestamp\":\"2022-08-22T13:14:48\"," +
    "   \"first_name\":{" +
    "      \"old\":\"rak\"," +
    "      \"new\":\"raki\"" +
    "   }," +
    "   \"fam_name\":{" +
    "      \"old\":\"gow\"," +
    "      \"new\":\"gowda\"" +
    "   }" +
    "}");
```

Transformation

```
JsonNode node = josson.getNode(
    "map(idno, user, operation, timestamp," +
    "    changes: entries().[value.isObject()]*.map(key::value))" +
    ".unwind(changes)");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

Output

```
[ {
  "idno" : 6473853,
  "user" : "GCA_GB",
  "operation" : "U",
  "timestamp" : "2022-08-22T13:14:48",
  "first_name" : {
    "old" : "rak",
    "new" : "raki"
  }
}, {
  "idno" : 6473853,
  "user" : "GCA_GB",
  "operation" : "U",
  "timestamp" : "2022-08-22T13:14:48",
  "fam_name" : {
    "old" : "gow",
    "new" : "gowda"
  }
} ]
```

Answer (score -1):

```java
package org.example;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;


public class GsonTest {
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public class oldNewClass{
        private String old;
        @SerializedName("new")
        private String _new;
    }
    @Getter @Setter
    public class SomeObject {
        private String idno;
        private String user;
        private String operation;
        private String timestamp;
        private oldNewClass first_name;
        private oldNewClass fam_name;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        SomeObject s = gson.fromJson("{\"idno\":6473853,\"user\":\"GCA_GB\",\"operation\":\"U\",\"timestamp\":\"2022-08-22T13:14:48\",\"first_name\":{\"old\":\"rak\",\"new\":\"raki\"},\"fam_name\":{\"old\":\"gow\",\"new\":\"gowda\"}}", SomeObject.class);
        /* Access various properties */
        System.out.println(s.getFirst_name().get_new());
        /* Manipulate the object and then convert it back to json using */
        String jsonString = gson.toJson(s);
    }
}
```

Try the above code. Here are two of the maven dependencies for it.

````xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.24</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>```
````

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Agree with **Pshemo** to create two separate JSON objects, here is an option:

```js
const statement = {"idno":6473853,"user":"GCA_GB","operation":"U","timestamp":"2022-08-22T13:14:48","first_name":{"old":"rak","new":"raki"},"fam_name":{"old":"gow","new":"gowda"}}

const noFamName = {...statement};
delete noFamName['fam_name'];

const noFirstName = {...statement}:
delete noFirstName['first_name']
```

Comment: could you please explain it more how will it works, what will be the output

Comment: This looks like JavaScript not Java.